# Time series plot not showing as desired in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have two columns that I want to make a time series plot from.

One of the columns is an irregular time column. A sample from it is also given below (n=50):

```
time = c("2010-03-12", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02",
"2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02",
"2010-06-02", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", 
"2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03",
"2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", 
"2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-04",
"2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", 
"2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04",
"2010-06-04", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-05", 
"2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07",
"2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", 
"2010-06-07", "2010-06-08", "2010-06-08",
"2010-06-08", "2010-06-08")
```

A sample of the x axes column is also given below (n=50):

```
x = c(700.00,   8800.96,    500.00,    300.00,    350.00,    200.00,    260.00,  
250.00,    400.00,   1000.00,    1300.00,    700.00,    500.00,    400.00,
150.00,    250.00,    5129.15,    300.00,     80.00,   1000.00,   
100.00,    650.00,    400.00,    200.00,    400.00,    100.00,    200.00,   
400.00,    500.00,    300.00,    200.00,    220.74,    122.39,   1400.00,   
3973.88,    200.00,    200.00,    100.00,   1000.00,    100.00,
1430.66,    400.00,    100.00,    100.00,    100.00,    221.51,   9753.63,    
150.00,    110.00,    250.00)
```

I plotted the time series in R by:

```
plot(cbind(time,x), type = "l")
```

The output plot is not what I expected, not descriptive at all. Any ideas on how to arrange the data to get a good time series plot that I can also work on to get the trend and seasonal plots?

Comment: Do you mean `plot(as.Date(time),x,type="l")`?

Comment: could you add the plot you're receiving? like laterow said, you need to use the as.Date function in R but you have multiple values for the same dates and one date that is much much earlier than the others, so I don't know what you're expecting to see

Answer (score 2):

First you need to format the input data a bit:

```
time <- c("2010-03-12", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", 
"2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-02", "2010-06-03", 
"2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", 
"2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", 
"2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-03", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", 
"2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", 
"2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-04", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-05", 
"2010-06-05", "2010-06-05", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07",
"2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", "2010-06-07", 
"2010-06-07", "2010-06-08", "2010-06-08",
"2010-06-08", "2010-06-08")

x <- c(700.00, 8800.96, 500.00, 300.00, 350.00, 200.00, 260.00,  
250.00, 400.00,   1000.00, 1300.00, 700.00, 500.00, 400.00,
150.00, 250.00, 5129.15, 300.00,  80.00,   1000.00,   
100.00, 650.00, 400.00, 200.00, 400.00, 100.00, 200.00,   
400.00, 500.00, 300.00, 200.00, 220.74, 122.39,   1400.00,   
3973.88, 200.00, 200.00, 100.00,   1000.00, 100.00,
1430.66, 400.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00,   221.51,   9753.63, 
150.00, 110.00, 250.00)
```

Then you need to follow [@Laterow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5805670/laterow)'s advice:

```
datetime <- as.Date(time)
```

The final plot will look like the following:

```
plot(cbind(datetime, x), type = "l", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", cex.axis=0.8)
axis(side=1, at=datetime, labels = time, las=2, cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Please note that you have seven different dates only and one of them is much earlier than others as [@Jonas Coussement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536872/jonas-coussement) commented.

Comment: I get a similar plot to what you have though mine is in years due to the large data set I'm working on. My challenge is how to get the forecast for such irregular dates, without using the 'forecast' command. Is there a way I can beat around the function?

Comment: State space models have ability to treat time series that have been observed irregularly over time. More details on the topic please find in [Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/) book, chapter "6.4 Missing Data Modifications". There are many R packages that implement irregular time series based on irregular time stamps: [its](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/its/index.html), [fts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fts/index.html), [tseries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/index.html).

Comment: You have been quite helpful, the irts function under the tseries package seems most helpful. The problem I have now though is converting the data classes to class 'irts'. I tried as.irts(object) but it's not working. My time column is of class 'Date' while the x column is of class 'numeric'.

Comment: The `object` is supposed to be a set of time-value pairs, and `time` is a numeric vector or a vector of class "POSIXct". So, first please convert the date points into the POSIXct format (`datetime <- as.POSIXct(time)`), then combine time and corresponding value together (`objmat <- cbind(datetime, x)`) and finally coerce this matrix (`irtsseries <- as.irts(objmat)`)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. As you might have guessed, I'm quite new to R.